# Adding UITableView to ViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I haven't developed any iOS apps in a while. I am fine with both swift and Objective-C but what I find different is adding a `UITableView` to ViewController. Before, I used to add a `UITableView` to ViewController, add the required datasource methods and the typical `UITableViewCell` object, and return the cell in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which would display empty cells depending on the number of rows I return. Now, I did everything the same, but the `UITableView` is empty and when I scroll I see the lines but not my `cell.textlabel.text` value, which I set. It seems now I am supposed to add `UITableViewCell` to the `UITableView` and remove the

```
   #pragma-mark TableView Datasource
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [_formTitles count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(cell==NULL)
    {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text=[_formTitles objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"Kaushik";
    return cell;
}
```

I can't find a simple post online regarding the same.
Can someone post what are the changes in the new iOS 9 in a simple manner?
Thank you

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That style of code should still work. The new approach that has been available for a number of years now is to register a class against the reuse identifier and the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will always return a cell, even if it needs to allocate one for you. Can you show more code?

Comment: It seems now we need to add a mandatory uitableviewcell to the table and set a reuseidentifer isn't it? before we don't used to do that

Comment: If you are using a storyboard then you would add a prototype cell and set its reuse identifier. The framework will then register this class against the reuse identifier for you. If you are creating the tableview programatically then you don't need to register the class but it makes for less code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You can also allocate and return cells yourself even if you are using a storyboard, but you wouldn't.  Can you show your full `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: Yeah thats what i understand. but i've got two problems 1. I am unable to see the lines between the cells . I can see the lines only when i scroll 2. I am getting some space on top of the table,i think that is the header. I set the height of header to 0.1 but still space persists Why is that? Is it due to the prototype cells in that pace? FYI: I've added autolayout

Comment: That code looks fine. How are you adding the tableview? Through nib? Storyboard? Code?

Comment: This doesn't address your issue at all, and is just being pedantic, but you should compare against nil, not NULL, when comparison involves Objective-C objects.   NULL is for pointer types.

Comment: The lines between cells being invisible is often from running on simulator with the window scaled.

Comment: This might not be your problem, but if you are testing on the simulator press cmd+1 or cmd+3 to resize the simulator and see if that solves one of your problems.  When you test on a small scaled simulator the separator lines are only visible when scrolling

Comment: I added the tableview in the storyboard and connected to viewcontroller. Yeah nil my bad

Comment: yeah the lines are visible in cmd+1 and 2 not in 3.Why's that?

Comment: Then did you set constraints on the tableview then?  Also, since you are using a storyboard scene you may as well just add the prototype cell and set its reuse identifer. That will save you some code, but I just tested adding a tableview in storyboard without setting up a prototype cell and it worked fine

Comment: yeah thats what i did.I added to the tableview to  view controller in storyboard and added constraints.Also added the protoypecells

Comment: Sounds like your constraints aren't doing what you want. If you have added a prototype cell and set the reuse identifier to "cell" then dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier will never return nil

Comment: No no.The problem now is that as you can see in the screenshot above. The table is displayed as expected.As suggested by MSU_Bulldog, the lines are visible only in cmd+1 and 2 but not in 3 .I don't know why is that happening.The other thing is the space on the top of the table. I think thats because of the prototype cells present in that place in the storyboard.How do i avoid the space? FYI: i've removed that if cell==nil since we have the prototype cells.SO it is just dequereuseidentifer

Comment: The lines aren't visible in ⌘-3 because the image is scaled down too much. A hairline line can't be seen at 50% scale. The space at the top will be because of your constraints. The prototype cell isn't actually part of the scene and doesn't take space.

Comment: I don't know, it is just table view with four constraints. There should not be a space on the top

Answer (score 0):

Right..For those of you who are still prefer to add a tableview to a viewcontroller.Here are the steps

1. In the ViewController drag and drop the tableview.Now instead of the lines which you see in the old Xcode.This time you would see a blank table view with the text " Table View prototype content" in the middle.
2. We usually create a tableviewcell only we doing anything different like adding more labels or image etc but hereafter it is required to add a tableviewcell in the tableview.Drag and drop a tableview onto the tableview.It will display as protype cells.One can select type of cell here itself as basic,value 1,value 2 or subtitle.Also **NEED TO SET THE REUSE IDENTIFIER IN THE STORYBOARD UTILITIES PANEL ON YOUR RIGHT**. At the end, you can select the tableview and add the missing constraints.
3. Implement the typical required datasource methods in your viewcontroller class.

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
         return 5;
     }

     ```
     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
         UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

         cell.textLabel.text=@"text";
         cell.detailTextLabel.text=@"DetailedText";
         return cell;
     }
     ```

The change here is that we dont require the usual if(cell==nil)
{..}
piece of code since we added the prototype cells to the storyboard.

Don;t forget to connect the delegate and datasource of the tableview to the viewcontroller.

This should display the tableview in your viewcontroller but i am getting a space on top of the tableview which i don't know why.Anyway this is how you add a tableview to a view controller using Objective-C language in iOS 9.3.

FYI: Guys if i've missed anything, please mention it in the comments

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

1. Put tableView to view controller and link it to viewcontroller.
2. link delegate and datasource of tableview to viewcontroller.
3. in

   `viewcontroller.h`

   ```
    @interface ViewController :<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
   ```
4. in `viewWillAppear` put

   ```
    tblService.delegate=self;
    tblService.dataSource=self;
   ```

   and your array elements.

   5.Impliment your tableview delegate method and datasource method .

   6.be sure you cell identifier equal the one put on storyboard.

this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/) will help you more to implement your first app and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RisoYQOqmMM).